# Can mutiple touch screens accept muti touch-dragging inputs on the same app (window spanning the monitors) at the same time?

Tags: linux, windows, multiple-monitors

I have an application with touch-drag inputs window spanning two touch screens. (for example, ms paint) In Windows, I can draw on the app window from either touch screen, but not both at the same time. I have to let go from one to draw with the other.

I'd like simultaneous drag input on multiple touch screens on the same app instance.

Perhaps the multi-touch input devices must be seen by the application as one device somehow? Is this possible in any OS? (I am open to multi-head (linux x11?) setups, but would love it if were in one app instance.) Thanks!

Comment: The application needs to support it. Also AFAIK X11 is not capable of "true" multitouch, but only gestures via a multitouch extension. Wayland is capable of truly relaying multitouch events to applications.