# Can mutiple touch screen monitors, accept muti touch-dragging inputs on the same app window spanning the monitors simulaniously?

Tags: linux, windows, android

I have an application with touch-drag inputs window spanning two touch screens. (for example, ms paint) In Windows, I can draw on the app window from either touch screen, but not both at the same time. I have to let go from one to draw with the other.

I'd like simultaneous drag input on multiple touch screens on the same app instance.

Perhaps the multi-touch input devices must be seen by the application as one device somehow? Is this possible in any OS? (I am open to multi-head (linux x11?) setups, but would love it if were in one app instance.) Thanks!

(edited for clarity.)

**Edit: I see that it is more appropriate to [ask this on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/1755472/can-mutiple-touch-screens-accept-muti-touch-dragging-inputs-on-the-same-app-win): My apologies.**  I would delete this but it has an answer, and I'm warned that I may loose the ability to post questions.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: With the exception of RDP connection (2016+), local multitouch-displays are limited to their own touch-zone respectively.

Comment: Thank you!
They have their own touch zone on different monitors seeing different parts of the desktop, but no simultaneous input.  Yes, It's one or the other in Windows.  Perhaps there's a way for multiple touch input devices to be treated as one multi-touch device, maybe that's default in linux? or it's otherwise possible to combine multiple multitouch devices (offset by respective affecting areas) into one emulated device? I'm still exploring.